# VNET peering with on-premise gateway transit not working properly

Tags: azure, site-to-site-vpn, azure-networking, virtual-network, peering

We have a VNET (let's call it `VN_MAIN`) that is configured to have a S2S VPN connection to our on-premise network. The VMs deployed within subnets of `VN_MAIN` are reachable from on-premise.

What I'm trying to do is to create another VNET (`VN_OTHER`) and make sure that you can reach on-premise from `VN_OTHER` and vice-versa, through `VN_MAIN` acting as a hub.

`VN_MAIN` has an address space of `10.123.128.0/20` (not created by me). I needed a `/16` address space for my new VNET and wanted to avoid overlap, so I created `VN_OTHER` with address space `10.230.0.0/16`.

Taking inspiration from the hub-spoke topology described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke), I've created a peering on each VNET:

- On `VN_MAIN`: `main-to-other-peering` to `VN_OTHER`, forwarded traffic allowed + gateway transit allowed
- On `VN_OTHER`: `other-to-main-peering`to `VN_MAIN`, forwarded traffic allowed + use remote gateways checked

Afterwards, to test this, I launched 2 linux machines: `machine-1` on `VN_MAIN` (subnet `10.123.129.0/24`) and `machine-2`on `VN_OTHER` (subnet `10.230.0.0/16` = the whole space).

According to my understanding of the article I linked, this should be enough for what I'm trying to accomplish. However, it doesn't work properly. Here are the pings I attempted:

- `machine-1` to `machine-2`: OK
- `machine-2` to `machine-1`: OK
- `my-laptop` to `machine-1`: OK
- `machine-1` to `my-laptop`: OK
- `my-laptop` to `machine-2`: NOT OK
- `machine-2` to `my-laptop`: NOT OK

So, the peering between the VNETs works, but the gateway transit does not, even though I believe I've done everything I was supposed to do to allow it. I am positive this is not an issue with any NSG rules.

Can anyone tell if there's something I am missing here please?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your onprem Gateway doesn’t have a route to the 10.230.0.0/16 (VN_Other) vía the S2S VPN

Comment: Yes that's a good point thanks. Wouldn't that only explain the ping from on-premise to the VNET ? If `VN_Main` is able to ping `my-laptop` in the current configuration, `VN_Other` should be too, shouldn't it ?

Comment: @valorl, what was the solution to the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not only do you need a route defined on premises to route thru the tunnel, but your vpn appliance on prem needs to be aware that it should allow traffic from that address space. Once you do that, it should work fine.